# Datediff function in Advantage SQl

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I am trying to calculate the number of days between 2 dates in advantage sql.
below code is what im trying to get but i dont know the syntax for advantage sql.

select datediff(day,'2-1-19','2-28-19') --in ms sql would give me 27 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `timestampdiff()`:

```
select timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_DAY, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-28')
```